# An equation in Advanced QM by J.J. Sakurai that I don't understand

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, scattering

In section 2.5 of Advanced QM by Sakurai, Sakurai gave an equation to calculate the dot product of two polarization vectors as following:$$
\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{(\alpha)}\cdot\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{(\alpha')}=\frac{1}{i\hbar}\sum_I[(\mathbf{x} \cdot\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{(\alpha)})_{AI}(\mathbf{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{(\alpha')})_{IA}-(\mathbf{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{(\alpha')})_{AI}(\mathbf{x}\cdot\boldsymbol{\epsilon}^{(\alpha)})_{IA}].
$$
$I$ means a set of complete intermediate states, and the subscript $AI$ means the operators are sandwiched between states $A$ and $I$.
$\alpha$ means polarization directions.

I don't understand why you can write like this. Could someone show the details?

Comment: Looks like he may be rewriting $\delta_{ij}$ as proportional to $[x_i, p_j]$ and then inserting the sum over states in between the operators. Try that.

Comment: It works. Thanks!@hft